# Does Facebook scan the photos I upload?

Tags: facebook, facial-recognition

I uploaded a photo of mine with my friend and tagged some random Facebook users of my friend list. After some time when I opened that post, Facebook is suggesting me to tag my friend who is in that picture. Facebook even shows my friend's name (Facebook name).

Is Facebook scanning photos we are uploading?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: yes.

Everything you send to Facebook is stored and processed, and that includes more than posts or pictures. All your likes, all links you click, all friends you check, how much time you spend on Facebook, how many times you use it, which hours you check. Everything.

They earn money by knowing everything possible about you and everyone you know. Making a profile of you so detailed that they can predict what you will like or dislike, and send you exact the things you like.

Comment: To be even more blunt, this is **the entire point of Facebook**.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's ability to recognise and automatically tag users in photos has been around for ***years*** (2011).

Your Facebook settings have the option to turn this off.

It is always important to understand and review the privacy settings of any social media site you use.

Comment: Facebook settings only present various options to you or not. Things happen anyway behind the scenes. If you delete something, you just can't see it anymore, but the object is stored there forever.

Comment: Settings to stop auto tag work. How photos are processed is another matter.